# ASP.NET Third party chart for showing live data

Tags: asp.net, live, charts

We are building a financial web application which requires a real time chart. Initially an empty chart will be shown to the customer with X-Axis from 08:00 to 18:00 with a gap of 2 hours, i.e 6 points. The Y-axis should be adjusted based on the price between these timings. Now, from 08:00 the client(browser) will send a JSON/Ajax request to the server for every 15sec(configurable time) to fetch the latest price. And then, the price needs to be updated on chart based on the time.

I have seen some third party controls but really aren't successfull to satisfy this requirement. Telerik controls doesn't have client side access to the chart because it renders as an image.

Could anyone please let me know a third party control to satisfy this requirment.

Thanks a lot.

Mahesh

Comment: How about using a Silverlight chart?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.As silverlight is not widespread, we have kept it as the last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like what you want

http://www.jscharts.com/